# How can I add lines under each cell in my table view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I was wondering how I would go about adding a separator line under each of my table view cells on Xcode **(using swift)** I want to make it so that under all of the cells other than the first cell it will add a separator.

Thank you in advance :D

Update:

Code that used to work for me.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let result = UIView()
    
    // recreate insets from existing ones in the table view
    let insets = tableView.separatorInset
    let width = tableView.bounds.width - insets.left - insets.right
    let sepFrame = CGRect(x: insets.left, y: -0.5, width: width, height: 0.5)
    
    // create layer with separator, setting color
    let sep = CALayer()
    sep.frame = sepFrame
    sep.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
    result.layer.addSublayer(sep)
    
    return result
}
```

The code above does the following within the old version however now doesn't add any extra lines.

Example of what I want:

[image: Screenshot of the result I used]

The setup that I have it as:

[image: Setup of the table]

Comment: you can add a dummy view in cell with 1px height so it will look like separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a view on bottom of uitableview cell and hide and unhide when required in cellForRowAt. Use following constraints for seperator view

[image]

Comment: does that mean that it isn't possible now? I was able to do it on my previous version but it doesn't seem to work on this one. I didn't have to add any other views or anything, it was just some code to add it, but doesn't seem to work on the newest version of Xcode

Comment: It is always possible to do that. Please share your code so that we might have better idea what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The code you shared adds a seperator in every new section not in every row. viewForFooterInSection is called once in a section

Comment: I updated with picture of what the app does to the tableview, I'm unsure how to recreate it

Comment: can you share all tableview datasource delegate functions

Answer (score 1):

Add a cell with the same width as the other cells and make the height 1~2 according to your demand after every regular cell.